# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.5:3306/prueba?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de conectarme a la base de datos pero me sale ese Error mi host hace ping con la Maquina Virtual Y he creado el usuario tarea1 y le he dado todos los permisos para la base de datos

Aquí esta mi código:

```
package Tarea1;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Prueba {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     String url="jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.5:3306/prueba?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC"; 
    
     try{ 
         Connection co = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"tarea1","1234");
         
      
         Statement instruction = co.createStatement();
         if(co!=null){
         System.out.println("Conexion establecida");
        }
    }catch(SQLException ex){
         ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
     }   
    }
    
}
```

Aqui os pongo el OutPut:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.5:3306/prueba?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:702)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
    at Tarea1.Prueba.main(Prueba.java:15)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

En un proyecto, necesitas un archivo .jar con el Driver JDBC de MySQL.

Este es independiente del sistema operativo sobre el que estés desarrollando

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=502728

Comment: En un proyecto maven se tiene que añadir un .jar, yo tenia entendido que no..